# Convert word into an array of 2 letters

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a String representing a word into an array of 2 letter elements.

For instance, I have word: believe

Then, I convert it to array of 2 letters.

The array what I expected should be: {{**be**},{**li**},{**ev**},{**e**}} or **be li ev e**

I tried char array (toCharArray()). Code I've tried:

```
String word="believe";
char[] new_word = word.toCharArray();
for(char letter:new_word){
   System.out.print(letter+" ");
}
```

But, its result is not what I expected.

Result: **b e l i e v e**

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The array what I expected should be: {{be},{li},{ev},{e}}

If you want to have an array that looks like this, you can use a 2D char array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String word="believe";  
    char[][] arr = getSplittedString(word);
    System.out.println("The array is: "+Arrays.deepToString(arr));
    for(char[] c : arr){
        System.out.print(c);
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
}

public static char[][] getSplittedString(String word){
    char[] new_word = word.toCharArray();
    char[][] word_splitted = new char[word.length()/2 + word.length()%2][];
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length()/2; i++){
        word_splitted[i] = new char[] {new_word[j++],new_word[j++]};
    }
    if(word.length()%2 != 0){
        word_splitted[word_splitted.length-1] = new char[]{new_word[j]};
    }
    return word_splitted;
}
```

Output:

```
The array is: [[b, e], [l, i], [e, v], [e]]
be li ev e
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like so,

```
public static String[] getTwoCharStrings(String in) {
    if (in == null) {
        return null;
    }
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
        if (sb.length() >= 2) {
            al.add(sb.toString());
            sb.setLength(0);
        }
        sb.append(in.charAt(i));
    }
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        al.add(sb.toString());
    }
    String [] r = new String[al.size()];
    return al.toArray(r);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word="believe";
    String[] r = getTwoCharStrings(word);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));
}
```

Output is

```
[be, li, ev, e]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

1. Determine the number of pairs of strings to return
2. Create an array to return
3. Iterate over the array picking a new pair of characters from the input string

Here is a compilable example that prints out the digraphs.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Digraph {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String word = "believe";
        final String[] substrings = digraphs(word);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(substrings));
    }

    private static String[] digraphs(final String word) {
        final int returnLength = word.length() / 2 + word.length() % 2;
        final String[] returns = new String[returnLength];

        for (int arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < returns.length; arrayIndex++) {
            final int start = arrayIndex * 2;
            int end = start + 2;
            if (end > word.length()) {
                end = word.length();
            }
            final String digraph = word.substring(start, end);
            returns[arrayIndex] = digraph;
        }
        return returns;
    }
}
```

The only thing to be careful of is making sure you deal with non-even length strings. As an alternative to the `word.length/2+word.length%2` you could use `Math.ceil(word.length/2d)`.

Answer (score 0):

One method of doing this would be to keep count as follows:

```
for( int i = 0; i < new_word.length; i++) {
    if (i == new_word.length - 1) {
        System.out.print(new_word[i]);
        break;
    }
    System.out.print(new_word[i] + "" + new_word[++i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: This will only work for even length strings - for "believe" you'll get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Done.. this should work with odd characters as well.

Comment: Your code is adding characters as numbers. The output I get with this code is: `199 213 219 e`

Comment: Result: **204 226 211 204 226 202 226**

Why like that anyway?

Comment: I just edited the answer to print them out as characters. I checked and the code works. I was doing it on the fly and forgot that number values are associated with characters.

Comment: @Speaky - you get the numbers because the characters have ASCII values corresponding to them. But strange that you got those numbers as I got something else. But I've now solved it to reflect the right answer.

Comment: I'm sorry,I typed the wrong number. I got **199 213 219 e** like @richard-miskin said. I already edited my last comment above once, so I can't edit it again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this

```
for(int i = 0; i < new_word.length; ++i) {
    char letter = new_word[i];
    System.out.print(letter);
    if ((i % 2) == 1) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```